# Is $R(su_{4})\cong R(so_{6})$?

Tags: lie-groups

This is one of small the unsettled questions I had in my senior project. I want to prove for type $D$ we have $R(T)$ is a free module over $R(G)$ by finding a basis. I think we should have,$R(G)\cong R(g)$, $R(T)\cong R(h_{g})$, but since $SO_{6}$ is not simply connected this probably does not work and I have to "ascend" to spin groups, but I do not know how.

Define the representation ring of a lie algebra to be the formal sums of its characters, it is not hard to show that $$R(su_{4})\cong \mathbb{Z}[x+y+z+w,xy+yz+zx+wz+wy+wz,xyz+yzw+xzw+xyw]/(xyzw-1)$$ and $$ R(h_{su_{4}})\cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z,w]/(xyzw-1)$$

a typical basis of $R(h_{su_{4}})$ over $R(su_{4})$ consists of $x^{i}y^{j}z^{k}, 0\le i\le 3, o\le j\le 2, 0\le k\le 1$.

I proved that the weight lattice of $su_{4}$ and $so_{6}$ are isomorphic, and their Weyl group are both isomorphic to $S_{4}$. So $R(h_{so_{6}})$ should be a free module over $R(so_{6})$ with rank 24 as well. But I found I could not use this to find a basis for $R(h_{so_{6}})$ over $R(so_{6})$, because we have:

$$R(so_{6})\cong \mathbb{Z}[x+y+z+x^{-1}+y^{-1}+z^{-1},x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}z^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}z^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}z^{-\frac{1}{2}},x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}z^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}z^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}]$$

the first is the standard representation with weights $\pm L_{i}$, the second and the third are the spin representations one obtain from clifford algebra or "ascend" to spin group(can be found at Fulton&Harris, Chapter 23.2 or [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=6GUH8ARxhp8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=fulton+harris&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ALmIT_rvAcTL0QH-_dH1CQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fulton%2520harris&f=true)). As one commentator noted I am not clear about the relationship between $R(so_{6})$ and $R(h_{so_{6}})$.

and $$R(h_{so_{6}})\cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z,x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1}]$$ because we know the two diagonal submatrices in $so_{6}$ must be skew-symmetric. From $A+D^{T}=0$ we conclude $T$ is isomorphic to $S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$. Thus we conclude this.

I thought it would be a simple change of variable to prove the two cases are just the same, but I found the isomorphism between $R(so_{6})$ and $R(su_{4})$ does not extend nicely to an isomorphism between $R(h_{so_{6}})$ and $R(h_{su_{4}})$. So I believe I must be confused. My advisor suggested me that maybe there is some subtly in $Spin_{6}$, but I still do not know how to estbalish an isomorphism or to find the basis right away.

Comment: I have worked with $R(G)$ quite a bit, but since I've never seen the notation before, what is $R(h_G)$ for a group/lie algebra $G$?

Comment: @ARupinski: $h$ is the Cartan subalgebra of $G$, to distinguish the two rings I use $R_{h_{G}}$.  

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't $R(h_{so_6})$ contain $R(so_6)$ as a subring?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am expecting. But I do not know what is wrong so I really need some help. 

Comment: The first one is the standard representation, the second and the third are the spin representations. 

Comment: I don't have time to do the calculation right now, but I'm pretty sure that's not the right presentation for $R(h_{SO_6})$, though I agree it is isomorphic to the Laurent ring you say. Why don't you add an explanation here on how you found that? 

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi: Sure. Added. 

Comment: what you added is a proof that $R(h_{so})$ is _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb Z[\cdots]$. I asked that you derive $R(so)$ and R(h_{so}) in parallel so that the inclusion of the first in the second becomes clear. 

Comment: Well, you wrote "I'm pretty sure that's not the right..". The standard representation is clear, and the spin representation comes from viewing $so_{6}$ inside of $\wedge V$ by clifford algebra. 

Comment: I wasn't explaining myself properly. Explicitly, $R(h_{so_6})$ is $\mathbb Z[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1},(xyz)^{1/2}]$. This is also isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1}]$, which is where your  confusion lies, I believe.

Comment: I do not get why the $[xyz]^{1/2}$ term appeared though this appeared in part of the sums in $R(g)$, and I could not write it down in the form $x^{\pm a}y^{\pm b}z^{\pm c}$ since $x,y,z$ bore no relations. But I believe with that base ring we could achieve the isomorphism I wanted. 

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi: Could you answer me? (or should I email you?)

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard fact that $Spin(6)$ and $SU(4)$ (hence $so_{6}$ and $su_{4}$) are isomorphic. An easy way to see this is to observe that $SU(4)$ is simply connected and acts on the exterior square of $\mathbb{C}^4$, preserving a (complex) quadratic form (coming form exterior squaring and $det=1$) and a real structure (a conjugate-linear involution, hodge star followed by conjugation) for which the quadratic form is definite. Then the equality of dimensions (and easy calculation of the kernel) shows that $SU(4)\to SO(6)$ is a double covering.

From a higher standpoint, you may also observe that the Dynkin diagrams for $D_3$ and $A_3$ are the same, hence the maximal compact subgroups of the corresponding simply connected complex Lie groups are isomorphic.

Comment: @BS: I understand. This is very helpful. My main obstacle is I do not know how to establish this isomorphism on the representation ring level, despite the proof you offered. I will try to think about this harder. 